# Exporting data into excel and giving hyperlinks

Tags: r, r-xlsx

I tried the code below for giving hyperlinks to another file

```
library(xlsx)

wb <- createWorkbook()
sheet1 <- createSheet(wb, "Sheet1")
rows <- createRow(sheet1, 1:10) # 10 rows
cells <- createCell(rows, colIndex=1:8) # 8 columns
links <- c("D://r datasets/sales data.xlsx")
names(links) <- c("hyperlinks")
for (row in 1:length(links)) {
  setCellValue(cells[[row,1]], names(links)[row])
  addHyperlink(cells[[row,1]], links[row])
}
saveWorkbook(wb, "links.xlsx")
shell.exec("links.xlsx")
```

but am getting error

> Error in .jcall(cell, "V", "setHyperlink", link) : 
>     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Address of hyperlink must be a valid URI

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be with the spaces. Replace the `links` with

```
links <- c("D:/rdatasets/salesdata.xlsx")
```

and it works. If you really need the spaces, you should be able to encode them them as `%20`, and it seems that excel figures it out.

```
links <- c("D:/r%20datasets/sales%20data.xlsx")
```